# How to generate a radio button form in a form_for block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know how to loop a combo box by using this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id , Category.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => false})%>
```

and now, I can do radio box using the radio box help:

```
  radio_button("user", "receive_newsletter", "yes")
```

But how can I do this in a form helper? thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't

```
<%= f.radio_button :receive_newsletter, "yes" %>
```

work?